# What's the best way to load MEF extensions based on solution's location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-extensions

We have an extension that invokes command line tools and DLLs that are constantly updated and deployed through source control. Users often work in different branches, each branch might have differences in these command line interfaces.

So I want to avoid having to re-install the vsix manually each time these files are updated or the user switches branches.

Instead, I want users to simply sync from perforce, and opening a solution will load the matching vsix automatically.

I could create a proxy extension that wraps all the functionality I need and then load an assembly dynamically that contains my implementation and invoke that from the proxy. But with MEF, there's so many entry points to creating extensions that I'd need to update the proxy just as often as I add features to our extension.

Perhaps there's a way to dynamically load an assembly containing MEF extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I have a blog post that details how to automatically update a vsix file if the version has been updated:

http://blog.ninlabs.com/2011/04/auto-update-visual-studio-extensions/

You may be able to adapt it to check a relative file path storing the vsix based on solution's path.